# Spring MVC with Facelets views

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, facelets

I have tried a dumb solution that use two "DispatcherServlets" to use facelets as a view technology for a Spring MVC web application, it was nice for a moment, facelets pages can get models from controllers, the problem is when a facelets page send a form object, here is how this web application is set up:

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

With this configuration this controller's method is working fine:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/garage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView get(){
       ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView() ;
       mav.setViewName("/faces/garage.xhtml") ;
       mav.addObject("listOfCars", carService.getCarList()) ;
       mav.addObject("hello", "Hello World From Spring Controller") ;
       return mav ;  
}
```

The problem in this application, is when submitting a form, the jsf tag , is always trying to resolve a "faces/*.xhtml" view.
solutions like this simply don't change anything.

```
  <h:form>
      <p>
         <h:inputText                    
             id="carMarque"
             title="Quelle est la marque du nouveau véhicule"
             value="#{NewCar.marque}">
             </h:inputText>                  
             <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Ajouter" action="/garage/new" />
      </p>  
 </h:form>
```

It just ends up with a ServletException

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: /newcar.xhtml @22,50 value="#{NewCar.marque}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'NewCar' resolved to null
```

I don't know if there is a way to fix that up.

Comment: I am not sure that this is a request dispatch issue as it sounds that the `action` is doing a FORWARD to the MVC dispatcher and this knows how to serve `newCar.xhtml` as the View. The problem might be that JSF has its own built in dependency injection for ManagedBeans like `NewCar` that runs seperate from Spring. This can be integrated by changing the EL Resolver in faces-config.xml. Here is a tutorial that demonstrates how this is done. http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/

Comment: You are not passing the object "NewCar" in the model.  thats y its failing..